# Make wordpress auto-redirect to the theme directory as root path in URLS

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my wordpress site, let's say I have an image that is located in:

`/wp-content/themes/root-theme/assets/img/image-1.png`

If I want to access this image in a blog post, when using the html editor in Wordpress I have to type out:

`<img src="/wp-content/themes/root-theme/assets/img/image-1.png" />`

This generates a url of:

`http://my-site.com/wp-content/themes/root-theme/assets/img/image-1.png"`

This is a massive pain. I'd much rather be able to write:

`<img src="/img/image-1.png" />`

That is, I want to make it possible to access my `assets` folder from the root directory, so that the image above could be accessed via:

`http://my-site.com/img/image-1.png`

Is this possible to do or would it majorly screw up the rest of the site?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the media manager, it will write the full link out for you, no need to type anything. Just above the editor click "Add media", select your image, click insert into post and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Use **bloginfo** function to get full url of your theme :

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/img/image-1.png" />
```

**Output:** http://my-site.com/wp-content/themes/root-theme/assets/img/image-1.png

[**Reference**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)